# How to convert NSUUID to NSData

Tags: objective-c, nsdata, uuid, nsuuid

I need to get `NSData` from `vendorIdentifier` without converting to `NSString`, clear bytes.
How to convert `NSUUID` using `getUUIDBytes:` to `NSData`?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
NSUUID *vendorIdentifier = [[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor];
uuid_t uuid;
[vendorIdentifier getUUIDBytes:uuid];

NSData *vendorData = [NSData dataWithBytes:uuid length:16];
```

Answer (score 8):

Use this to get the `vendorIdentifier` as `Data` (Swift 4):

```
var uuidBytes = UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor!.uuid
let uuidData = NSData(bytes: &uuidBytes, length: 16) as Data
```

Keep in mind to guard against `UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor` being nil as the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidevice/1620059-identifierforvendor) says.

---

Original answer (Swift 2 Version):

```
var uuidBytes: [UInt8] = [UInt8](count: 16, repeatedValue: 0)
UIDevice.currentDevice().identifierForVendor!.getUUIDBytes(&uuidBytes)
let uuidData = NSData(bytes: &uuidBytes, length: 16)
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift 3 Version:

```
let vendorId = UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor!
let uuidBytes = Mirror(reflecting: vendorId.uuid).children.map { $0.1 as! UInt8 }
let data = Data(bytes: uuidBytes)
```